# Excel update query putting all data in row 1

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm using an oledbconnection to connect to an excel spreadsheet

Connection string:

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" +
                             Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "tmp\\" + Session["Id"] + ".xlsx;" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"";
```

Update query:

```
cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Contributions$B6:B6] SET F1 = 'value'", excelConn);
```

However, the data is being set in cell B1, not B6.  All other queries are also adding the data in row 1, but the correct column...any ideas?

Comment: Off the top of my head, isn't there supposed to be an ! separating the tab name and range?

Comment: @CharlesMay I don't *think* so...I've not seen any examples like that